# allocate an std map with list pointer value in c++

Tags: c++, list, pointers, dictionary, std

I'm trying to allocate a list for each key of my std map, but using the new operator I obtain some errors (no predefined constructor is find and others), why?

My code is like this one:

```
std::map<QString, *std::list<ExecutionGUIObject*>> execEvtMap;

execEvtMap["t1"] = new std::list<ExecutionGUIObject*>;
```

Comment: Please include the exact text of the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by [Frerich Raabe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31959172/3233393), it's a minor syntax error in your map declaration. But you gain nothing by allocating the `std::list`'s dynamically, so why seek trouble ? Just use a map of lists.

```
std::map<QString, std::list<ExecutionGUIObject*>> execEvtMap;

// Creates a new (empty) list for key "t1" if one does not already exist.
void(execEvtMap["t1"]);

// Creates a new list for key "t1", or clears the existing one.
execEvtMap["t1"].clear();

// Erases a key and its list
execEvtMap.erase("t1");
```

If this maps owns the `ExecutionGUIObject`'s, you'll want to tweak that too :

```
std::map<QString, std::list<std::unique_ptr<ExecutionGUIObject>>> execEvtMap;
```

Comment: and if I have to expose the lists from a class (like a get method) the efficiency of the two methods is the same? @Quentin

Comment: @Daniel Such as `std::list<...> &getList(QString key);` ? Yes, same cost. In fact, you can only see it speed up by cutting down on the dynamic allocations. Plus, no wild owning raw pointers to manage.

Answer (score 4):

```
*std::list<ExecutionGUIObject*>
```

is not a valid type and hence not a valid argument to the `std::map` template. You probably meant

```
std::list<ExecutionGUIObject*>*
```

which means 'pointer to list of pointers to ExecutionGUIObject objects'.